# How to make RSS Feeds for my Google+ Profile?

Tags: rss, google-plus

After the shut down of http://plusfeed.appspot.com is there any way to make RSS Feeds for my Google+ profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found this http://plusfeed2.appspot.com

Comment: That's likely to eventually suffer the same fate, though, since large-scale use of Google APIs is not free.  Another option is to set up your own instance of it, there's a link to the source code on the original Plusfeed site.

Comment: Plusfeed2 is now gone. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I've been planning on generating an RSS feed of my Google+ posts with https://github.com/jacoby/Plus2RSS

Answer (score 0):

For a fee, you can sign up for http://www.pluss.es and get an RSS feed of your public Google+ posts.

As of this writing, under "Settings", it says:

> For a single, once off payment of US$15.00 you will receive a Vanity
>   URL of your choosing (subject to availability) and an RSS feed.

See http://www.pluss.es/103697821787469756035/rss.xml as an example RSS feed from the [creator of Plusses, Daniel Treadwell](http://www.pluss.es/103697821787469756035/).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a way to create RSS feed but you can try [BazQux Reader](http://bazqux.com) which directly supports reading of Google+ pages.